# How to hide an element only in homepage?

Tags: twig, opencart-3

Trying to do "if homepage hide " a button.

Current code is here...

```
  <div class="mobile-bar sticky-bar">
            {% if j3.settings.get('mobileCustomMenuStatus1') %}
      <a class="mobile-custom-menu mobile-custom-menu-1" href="{{ j3.settings.get('mobileCustomMenuLink1.href') }}" {{ j3.linkAttrs(j3.settings.get('mobileCustomMenuLink1.attrs')) }} style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:-30px">
        {{ j3.countBadge(j3.settings.get('mobileCustomMenuLink1.name'), j3.cache.update(j3.settings.get('mobileCustomMenuLink1.total')), j3.settings.get('mobileCustomMenuLink1.classes')) }}
      </a>
      
      {% endif %}
      {% if j3.settings.get('mobileCustomMenuStatus2') %}
      <a class="mobile-custom-menu mobile-custom-menu-2" href="{{ j3.settings.get('mobileCustomMenuLink2.href') }}" {{ j3.linkAttrs(j3.settings.get('mobileCustomMenuLink2.attrs')) }}>
        {{ j3.countBadge(j3.settings.get('mobileCustomMenuLink2.name'), j3.cache.update(j3.settings.get('mobileCustomMenuLink2.total')), j3.settings.get('mobileCustomMenuLink2.classes')) }}
      </a>
      {% endif %}
```

Comment: Are you using any framework or not?

Comment: Yes, i am using Journal 3 Theme in Opencart

Comment: Unsure if this will work but a quick google search informs me of the variable `breadcrumbs`. If the length of this is 1, then you should be at the homepage `{% if breadcrumbs|default([])|length == 1 %}....{% endif %}`

Comment: Very clever! But unfortunately this didn't worked for me. Breadcrumps are disabled in mobile version. Thanks for helping anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the current page within a `$data` variable in your menu controller just like this:

```
$data['current_url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Within your twig file you can check it's value against whatever you want. This can be achived using a small `vqmod` or `ocextension`.